# Getting errors at a simple Android app concerning the layout xml file

Tags: android, xml

So I tried the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.slidenerd.sample.customdesign.MainActivity"
    android:background="#252525">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="0:00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The errors I am getting are these

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
E:\AndroidProjects\Tutorials\CustomDesign\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(17, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/textView').
E:\AndroidProjects\Tutorials\CustomDesign\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(17, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/textView').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 21.791 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

In contrast the following works correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.slidenerd.sample.customdesign.MainActivity"
    android:background="#252525">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="0:00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't understand why the first doesn't work. Is it wrong to arrange the various items based on an item that is placed at the center of the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with
>   value '@id/textView').

It's trying to tell you that you're using an id that hasn't been initialized yet. To avoid this, you should be able to use the first layout as long you specify "android:layout_above="@+id/textView" (The "+" needs to be there in @+id)

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView"   <-- this guy
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first one this line **android:layout_above="@id/textView"**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

refers to an element(textview) that has not been read yet from the xml parser. Just change the order: (First textview then imageview in the xml)

P.S.: `tools:context="com.slidenerd.sample.customdesign.MainActivity"` is unnecessary because thats not your project